# Finding a curve in S^n whose velocity vector is a given vector

Tags: manifolds, tangent-spaces

I want to to prove $T_x(S^n)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}|<x,y>=0\}$. For that I want to find a curve in $S^n$ whose velocity vector is a given vector, i.e., if $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ then I should find a curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S^n$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma^{'}(0)=y$. Can you please help to find this.

Comment: What is your definition of tangent space?

Comment: Suggestion: Parametrize the great circle starting at $x$ and with initial velocity $y$. If you don't see how to do this, perhaps sketch the unit circle in the plane.